# Replace part of a metadata content url using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, metadata, blogger

Here is my raw HTML:

```
<meta name='twitter:image' expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'/>
```

And here is the result on the page

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-DmLY0uHInEw/Ut45x9vmxAI/AAAAAAAADlw/4O6366ds6G0/s72-c/End_of_the_World_as_we_know_it.png">
```

Here is my javascript (which I'm sure is full of mistakes)

```
$('meta').each(function () {
var href = $(this).attr('content').replace("s72-c", "s1600");
});
```

**What I want to do:** 
I need to replace **s72-c** in my metadata content url with **s1600**.

I've tried everything, but it's not working and I'm not very good with jquery :/ Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to actually set the new content attribute. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('meta').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            href = $this.attr('content').replace("s72-c", "s1600");

        // now set it 
        $this.attr('content', href); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that's not working.

Comment: where is your script? before the meta tags or after the meta tags?

Comment: I've tried before and after, inside <head> and inside <body>. No luck :/ I'm using Blogger as you can probably see from the image URL above. Don't know if that helps you out?

Answer (score 0):

You can make this happen with one line of code, no need for each function:

```
$("meta").attr("content", function(){return $(this).attr("content").replace("s72-c", "s1600")});
```

Comment: I just checked this with your meta from above, The only thing I can think that might make this not work is if the dashes are different, there are 3 kinds of dashes , make sure they are identical in the meta and the javascript.